# Python - lxml / Get full content of xpath

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Using Twitter just for example, this code scrapes the 5th tweet from a twitter page. The page contains a link, except when I try to pull it up using lxml and xpath, it only displays the text cutting the link off the end.

**Script:**

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

xpathselector = "/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/ol/li[5]/div/div/p"
url =  "https://twitter.com/memphismayfire"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
result = tree.xpath(xpathselector)

print result[0].text
```

**Prints:**

> 'Miles Away' Acoustic is available on iTunes! Who's downloaded the single?! Let's get it up the Singles Chart!! Link:

**HTML from xPath Location:**

```
<p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text">'Miles Away' Acoustic is available on iTunes! Who's downloaded the single?! Let's get it up the Singles Chart!! Link: <a title="http://smarturl.it/mmf-miles-away" target="_blank" class="twitter-timeline-link" data-expanded-url="http://smarturl.it/mmf-miles-away" dir="ltr" rel="nofollow" href="http://t.co/fU2hVqAiSq" f52ae163cfcf0237f="true"><span class="tco-ellipsis"></span><span class="invisible">http://</span><span class="js-display-url">smarturl.it/mmf-miles-away</span><span class="invisible"></span><span class="tco-ellipsis"><span class="invisible">&nbsp;</span></span></a><div ida2bb72480="_p_mzkte2cwofawsu3r.t.co" style="cursor: pointer; width: 16px; height: 16px;display: inline-block;">&nbsp;</div></p>
```

What's the best method to print the entire contents of the xpath instead of just the text? Thanks for the help!

Comment: For those who is going to use lxml.etree, refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280486/pylint-error-message-e1101-module-lxml-etree-has-no-strip-tags-member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [lxml.etree.tostring](http://lxml.de/api.html#serialisation):

```
print etree.tostring(result[0])
```